# Getting a single Variable from the URL in javascript

Tags: javascript, url

So I need to get a variable from a url, a site name, and I have some code, but I keep getting an undefined return. Here's my code to get the variable.

```
function getSite(variable){
            var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
            var vars = query.split("&");
            for(var i=0; i<vars.length;i++){
                var pair = vars[i].split("=");
                if(pair[0] == variable){
                    return pair[1];
                }
            }
        }
```

So any help? The url for example is: localhost/findsite.html?siteId=external1

Comment: That should work fine.

Comment: It works, just make sure you are passing the right value...

Comment: It didn't originally work, but now it decides to. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what substring is supposed to do in here, but try this code

```
var getSite = function(variable){
var query = window.location.search.split("?")[1];
var vars = query.split("&");
for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
    if (pair[0] == variable) {
        return pair[1];
    }
}
}
```

you can see the values that you passed working in it here http://jsfiddle.net/vwbozvr7/1/